# Nested dictionary to line graph - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

How can I get the following nested dictionary into a line graph using matplotlib?

Ideally on the x axis I have each poet's name and 4 lines on the graph, each for every key (average sentence length, number of sentences, longest, shortest).

```py
poemsD = {'Maya Angelou': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 16.68,
  'Number of sentences': 40,
  'Longest': 45,
  'Shortest': 2},
 'Amanda Gorman': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 14.49,
  'Number of sentences': 49,
  'Longest': 38,
  'Shortest': 3},
 'Elizabeth Alexander': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 14.57,
  'Number of sentences': 23,
  'Longest': 40,
  'Shortest': 1},
 'Miller Williams': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 12.83,
  'Number of sentences': 24,
  'Longest': 39,
  'Shortest': 2},
 'Richard Blanco': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 34.53,
  'Number of sentences': 17,
  'Longest': 63,
  'Shortest': 1},
 'Robert Frost': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 30.25,
  'Number of sentences': 4,
  'Longest': 37,
  'Shortest': 25}}
```

Comment: Most people will not be happy if you just ask for code without trying something first.

Comment: @StephanyBernazzani they're right, although they could've been less snarky. This website has a pretty strict etiquette. See the [intro tour,](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the [help center,](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and this post on [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My comment is definitely not un-nice, but anyway you can start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449741/plotting-multiple-lines-in-python

Comment: Just a heads-up: `Length` is misspelled. It's written as `Lenght` in your code.

Comment: It's consistently wrong so it only makes the output misspelled.

Comment: ...hence why I'm pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to it by creating a Pandas dataframe and plotting it:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

poemsD = {'Maya Angelou': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 16.68, 'Number of sentences': 40, 'Longest': 45, 'Shortest': 2},
          'Amanda Gorman': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 14.49, 'Number of sentences': 49, 'Longest': 38, 'Shortest': 3},
          'Elizabeth Alexander': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 14.57, 'Number of sentences': 23, 'Longest': 40, 'Shortest': 1},
          'Miller Williams': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 12.83, 'Number of sentences': 24, 'Longest': 39, 'Shortest': 2},
          'Richard Blanco': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 34.53, 'Number of sentences': 17, 'Longest': 63, 'Shortest': 1},
          'Robert Frost': {'Average Sentence Lenght': 30.25, 'Number of sentences': 4, 'Longest': 37, 'Shortest': 25}}

df = pd.DataFrame(poemsD)
df2 = df.transpose()
df2.plot(figsize = (10,8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

A better visualization would be a bar graph.  This is very easy to do by changing one line of the code:

```
df2.plot(figsize = (10,8), kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

Comment: I know you're just providing OP with an answer, but *wow* that is an *awful* visualization for this data. OP, please consider an alternate visualization, as this graph should never actually see the light of day.

Comment: @blorgon I agree.  The proper visualization would be a multi-bar graph, but this is what OP asked for.

Comment: @blorgon I edited the answer to also include a bar graph.

Comment: So much better. Props on going the extra mile lol.

Comment: I can now see why this is not a good visualization and I appreciate showing me the multi-bar graph. It def looks clearer and is a more efficient way of displaying the data!