# Plot multiple graph from one csv file in same plot without using pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a code for a pandemic simulation. I have a csv file with data from 3 groups:
S (Susceptible) –
I (Infectious) –
R (Recovered) – .
I want to plot all three lists (s, i, r) in the same 2d plot. So that we can see three graphs in the same plot. Where the x axis is days and the y axis is in percentage (eg from 0 to 1). I have problem with making these plots, Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = []
i = []
r = []
with open("pan.csv","r") as f:
    lis = [line.split(",") for line in f]    
    for n in range(1,121):
        s.append(int(lis[n][0]))
        i.append(float(lis[n][1]))
        r.append(float(lis[n][2]))
      
n_list= [s, i, r]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

w = [s, i, r]
w_np = np.array(w)

# ax.plot(s, range(1)) here I have the problem

plt.show()
```

anyone can help me for plotting?

Trying to plot three 2d plots (x from three lists and y between 0-1 in percentage) in same plot.

Comment: Please try and search before you post a question, here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449741/plotting-multiple-lines-in-python)

Comment: `import pandas as pd`, `df = pd.read_csv('pan.csv')`, and `ax = df.plot(figsize=(6, 6))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using NumPy, you can do this

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                       
                                                                                                                      
# optional, see below
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator                                                                             

                                                                                                                      
s, i, r = np.genfromtxt("pan.csv", delimiter=',', unpack=True)                                                        
                                                                                                                      
days = np.arange(1, len(s)+1, dtype=int)                                                                              
                                                                                                                      
fig = plt.figure()                                                                                                    
ax = fig.add_subplot()                                                                                                
                                                                                                                      
ax.plot(days, s)                                                                                                      
ax.plot(days, i)                                                                                                      
ax.plot(days, r)                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                      
# This is optional: it will enforce axis ticks to be integers
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))                                                                 
                                                                                                                      
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you JustLearning and Tech Support Pakistan for answers, much appreciated. I tried to plot the graphs, but the graphs don't show the right value.

Comment: Your response is unhelpful. Show the error and/or what went wrong.

Comment: I can't plot the graph, I get an error that is from line 362-line 601: ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #362 (got 1 columns instead of 4)
    Line #363 (got 1 columns instead of 4)
    Line #364 (got 1 columns instead of 4)
    Line #365 (got 1 columns instead of 4)

Answer (score 0):

**Normalize the data to percentages and use the plot function for each group.**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = []
i = []
r = []
with open("pan.csv", "r") as f:
lis = [line.split(",") for line in f]
for n in range(1, 121):
    s.append(int(lis[n][0]))
    i.append(float(lis[n][1]))
    r.append(float(lis[n][2]))

s = np.array(s)
i = np.array(i)
r = np.array(r)

s_percentage = s / (s + i + r)
i_percentage = i / (s + i + r)
r_percentage = r / (s + i + r)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(s_percentage, label='Susceptible')
ax.plot(i_percentage, label='Infectious')
ax.plot(r_percentage, label='Recovered')

ax.set_xlabel('Days')
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage')
ax.set_title('Pandemic Simulation')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you JustLearning and Tech Support Pakistan for answers, much appreciated. I tried to plot the graphs, but the graphs don't show the right value.